# Wordpress Woocommerce wp->insert keeps give duplicates

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use the following Platforms
Woocommerce - Version 4.9.0
WordPress - Version 5.6

I'm getting wp_posts from an external source SQL server I connect fine no problem, the problem I have is when I import from the external source to WordPress I get duplicates and need help to sort it out

```
<?php
    require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
    // Connect test database
    $serverName = "sqlserver"; //c6140c606f53.sn.mynetname.net\PALLADIUMSQL,1435 
      $connectionOptions = array("Database"=>"database",  
                                  "UID"=>"user", 
                                  "PWD"=>"password");  
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);  
    // Check connection
    if($conn == false) {
      echo "failed";
      die(sqlsrv_errors());
    }
/* Begin the transaction. 
if ( sqlsrv_begin_transaction( $conn ) === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ));
}*/
    // echo "Connected successfully";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl'";
    $sql_products = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

    global $wpdb;
    $where = "WHERE ID = ".$row['intProductId']."";
    $wherre = "WHERE post_id = ".$row['intProductId']."";
        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql_products, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $wpdb->insert(''. $wpdb->prefix . 'posts', array('post_title' => $row['strDesc'], 'post_type' => 'product'));
        $product_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
        $wpdb->insert(''. $wpdb->prefix . 'post_meta', array('post_id' => $row['intProductId'], 'meta_key' => '_sku','meta_value' => $row['strPartNumber'])); 
            
        if (sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql)) {
               //echo "Name:".$row['strDesc']." - SKU: ". $row['strPartNumber']. " - Product ID: ".$row['intProductId']."<br/>";
               ///echo " - Inserted successfully\n <br/>";
         
}
// else {
//                die(sqlsrv_errors());
//            }
    }

    sqlsrv_close($conn);

    header("Location: http://website header");
    die();
    
?>
```

Why is duplicating the whole time?

EDITED
OK SO I CHANGED THE SCRIPT A BIT TO THE FOLLOOWING

```
<?php
    require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
     // Connect Palladium database
      require_once('inc/db.php');
      
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);  
    // Check connection
    if($conn == false) {
      echo "failed";
      die(sqlsrv_errors());
    }
    // echo "Connected successfully";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.tblInv";
    $sql_products = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

    global $wpdb;
    $woo_products = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ". $wpdb->prefix . "posts WHERE post_type = 'product'");
    //foreach ($woo_products as $woo_product) {
        //$wpdb->delete(''. $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta', array('post_id' => $woo_product->ID));
    //}
    $wpdb->delete(''. $wpdb->prefix . 'posts', array('post_type' => 'product'));
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql_products, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        // echo $row['name'];
        if (!empty ($row['intProductId'])){
        $wpdb->insert(''. $wpdb->prefix . 'posts', array('post_title' => $row['strDesc'], 'post_content' => $row['strExtendedDesc'], 'post_type' => 'product', 'ID' => $row['intProductId'] ));
        
        if ( ! add_post_meta( $row['intProductId'], '_sku', $row['strPartNumber'], true ) ) { 
   update_post_meta ( $row['intProductId'], '_sku', $row['strPartNumber']);
        }
        } elseif(!empty ($row['strPartNumber']) && empty($row['intProductId'])) {
        $wpdb->insert(''. $wpdb->prefix . 'posts', array('post_title' => $row['strDesc'], 'post_content' => $row['strExtendedDesc'], 'post_type' => 'product' ));
        $post_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
        if ( ! add_post_meta( $post_id, '_sku', $row['strPartNumber'], true ) ) { 
   update_post_meta ( $post_id, '_sku', $row['strPartNumber']);
    }
    }
}

    sqlsrv_close($conn);

    header("Location: https://localhost/wp-admin/admin.php?page=product-manage");
    die();
    
?>
```

this works for me, the only problem now is that it keeps adding an extra product example if there is 1000 on SQL server and I import to WordPress, WordPress stats that there are 1001 products.

I would like to keep the post meta as this is where the images, categories and SKU's is stored

P.S when I run the script it brings up the errors that there is the duplicate primary key

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking if the post already exist or not, so you're probably getting stuck in an infinite loop.

Checking for the post title should be enough

```
<?php
// ... while
if( ! get_page_by_title( $row['strDesc'] ) ) { 
  // ... your loop content
}; ?>
```

---

### Learn more

- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/112650/190376

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But the $row['strDesc'] will keep changing but the ID will keep the same that will not change at all, How will I do it for ID, I'm new to WordPress. I tried if( ! get_product($row['intProductId']) ) { // ... your loop content}; as the ID is WordPress primary key. but it still loops.

Comment: `$row['intProductId']` or `$wpdb->insert_id` i guess.